# Passing Data-id of an Object to Bootstrap Modal form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Good day.

I have a task list which has a Delete button in the task field for managing the task.
I am looking how to pass a task parameter containing ID (after pushing a Delete button) to the Bootstrap Modal.

---

My target is to click the "trash" icon on the task and to show the modal, and only in modal to confirm the deletion.

### Here is the button wrapped in modal

```
`<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete task">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteTaskModal">
                <button class="deleteTask far fa-trash-alt" data-id='{id}'></button>
              </a></span>`
```

### Here is the modal itself.

I want to use the modal to confirm Deleting the task.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteTaskModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleformModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="" action="" method="">
          <div class="modal-header">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Do you want to delete this task?</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Task</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

### Here is Jquery Script

I tried to catch the ID of the "trigger" and pass it to Modal

```
$(".modal fade #deleteTaskModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) //Button that triggered the modal
    var id = button.data('id');
    var url = '/delete/' + id;
    if (confirm('Delete task')) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function(result) {
          console.log("Deleting task...");
          window.location.href = '/';
        },
        error: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just a guess, If you are using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for button, shouldn't `data-id='{id}'` be `data-id='${id}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there though you were not `targeting` the right `element` in your modal open.

Since you have an `a` element and `button` is inside the `a` which contains the `data-id`

You need to watch for the `eventTarget` and then use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the button and get the data id from it which will be passed via `ajax`

```
var id = button.find('button').data('id') //need to find the button and get id
```

In addition, you also need an event handler which will `click` function inside your modal `open` which will trigger when you click on **Delete task** button in your modal.

Lastly I have added a modal `close` option as well which will happen ajax success - I have fixed up your `code` and is working as intended.

**Live Working Demo:** (Showing the data-id in console.log and click button working)

```js
$("#deleteTaskModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) //Button that triggered the modal
  var id = button.find('button').data('id') //need to find the button and get id
  var url = '/delete/' + id; //url

  console.log('data-id= ' + id) //15

  //Click delete task in modal
  $(document).on('click', '.delete_task', function() {
    if (confirm('Delete task')) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function(result) {
          $('#deleteTaskModal').modal('hide') //hide modal on success
          console.log("Deleting task...");
          window.location.href = '/';
        },
        error: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete task">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteTaskModal">
        <button class="deleteTask fas fa-trash-alt" data-id='15'></button>
    </a>
</span>

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteTaskModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleformModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="" action="" method="">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Do you want to delete this task?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delete_task">Delete Task</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```